# When to use Get vs Needs

Tags: programming, packages, function-comparison

When should I use `<<` vs `Needs`? I just always use `Needs` as `<<` seems less safe. I tried to find the answer in the documentation, but all it really seems to say is that `Needs` uses `Get`. My understanding is that `Needs` will only do the import once, whereas `Get` will happily do it again. So is this just a style issue? Or are there reasons to use one or the other?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

#### `Needs` versus `Get`

> `<<name`
>   reads in a file, evaluating each expression in it, and returning the last one.

(`<<` is shorthand for `Get`.)

> `` Needs["context`"] `` loads an appropriate file **if the specified context is not already in `$Packages`**.

`Needs` is normally appropriate for making sure that a package has been loaded, but when you need to force the package to reload you want `Get`.  One simple example of the difference is if you have loaded the Notation package but closed the Palette.  Calling `` Needs["Notation`"] `` will not reload the package, and *will not* cause the Palette to be re-displayed, whereas `` Get["Notation`"] `` will.

---

`Get` can be used for loading several different formats containing data or definitions, in addition to formal packages. See [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/2008/121) for an overview of such methods.

---

A related function that deserves mentioning is [`DeclarePackage`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/DeclarePackage.html).  While `Get` does a hard load and `Needs` does a soft one, `DeclarePackage` does a *delayed* load.  That is, it only loads the package when a certain Symbol (from a list of one or more) is first used.  For example if you *might* want to use functions from the Calendar package you do not need to load it into memory, but rather may use:

```
DeclarePackage["Calendar`", {"DayOfWeek", "DaysPlus", "DaysBetween"}]
```

Now if any of those three functions are used the Calendar package will be transparently loaded and the function will work.  Be aware that if other function names from the package are used before one of these three you may create a [shadowing](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3294/121) problem.  You could add *all* package Symbols to the `DeclarePackage` statement, or you could just be aware of the problem and act accordingly.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks for the example, I roughly understood the semantics, but not when I would care about the difference. Makes sense now.

Comment: The most obvious difference seems to be that they take completely different arguments. Specifically how do I use Needs to load a package in a `.m` file at some path?

Answer (score 32):

The main difference has been mentioned by Mr.Wizard, and another common situation where you want `Get` instead of `Needs` is during development, when you have changed something in a package file and want to reload with these changes applied (which will of course need some care that this reload is working correctly).

But there is another big difference: `Needs` insists on a correct package format and will complain when the .m file doesn't correctly create a context which matches the file name and path. `Get` will instead load every file with correct Mathematica InputForm syntax. That means that you can e.g. use `Put` and `Get` to save and load arbitrary mathematica expressions to file, which would not be possible with `Needs`.

Comment: Excellent points. +1

Comment: +1, I was about to add this after reading Wiz's answer