# How to reliably reload package after change?

Tags: evaluation

I'm using IntelliJ Idea with a Mathematica plugin to develop Mathematica application. I keep IntelliJ and Mathematica opened at the same time. I would like to change something in the IDE, evaluate notebook in the Mathematica and see updated result, but Mathematica fails to see changes in my code.

My application consists of several subpackages, and `Kernel/init.m` looks like

```
Get["MyPackage`A`"]
Get["MyPackage`B`"]
...
```

Notebook is something like

```
Quit[]
Get["MyPackage`"]
SomeFunctionFromMyPackage[]
```

And I've also tried

```
Needs["Utilities`CleanSlate`"] (* inside initialization cell *)
CleanSlate[]
Get["MyPackage`"]
SomeFunctionFromMyPackage[]
```

Let's say I changed `SomeFunctionFromMyPackage`, saved `.m` file` hit "Evaluate notebook" and hoping to see result changing, but this doesn't happen. Result is not getting updated. I've tried to introduce syntax error in function, Mathematica doesn't react at all.

The only way to force Mathematica to actually reload my package is to restart it.

It's driving me crazy, what am I doing wrong?

**Upd**

Such strange problems were caused by the fact that subpackages inside application depend on each other with `Needs` instead of `Get`. When I changed it to `Get` the problems went away.

Comment: So you say you *actually quit the kernel* and loaded the package again, and it didn't see the changes?  But when you restarted the *front end* then it did?  That sounds rather unlikely, so please check carefully again.

Comment: @Szabolcs, ok, I checked again. The problem is in "Evaluate notebook". When I manually evaluate cells from top to the bottom, it works as expected. Why?

Comment: Probably because `Quit[]` cancels all further evaluations by default.

Comment: @Szabolcs, ouch, I see.. Then my question stays the same, what is convenient and reliable way to reevaluate notebook after package changed?

Comment: I once wrote a package to cleanly reload packages. A brief description is in [this post](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/78338/81).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There isn't a fully general way to reload packages because packages can do just about anything in principle, not just create definitions.

I recommend that you write your package in a way that simply using `Get` again will properly re-set its state.  Assuming that all your package does is issue definitions, you could do something like this:

```
BeginPackage["MyPack`"];

Unprotect["MyPack`*"];
ClearAll["MyPack`*"];
ClearAll["MyPack`Private`*"];

Foo::usage = "";

Begin["`Private`"];

helper[x_] := x^2
Foo[x_] := 2*helper[x]

End[];
Protect["MyPack`*"];
EndPackage[];
```

But in general there's a lot more a package can do than issue definitions.  For example, it can cache results ([MaTeX](https://github.com/szhorvat/MaTeX)), it can load or save some persistent configuration ([MaTeX](https://github.com/szhorvat/MaTeX), [MATLink](http://matlink.org/)), it can create temporary files and directories to work with, or some other kind of state that persists throughout the session, such as connecting to other programs ([MATLink](http://matlink.org/)), it may load LibraryLink functions that must be unloaded before they can be safely reloaded ([IGraph/M](https://github.com/szhorvat/IGraphM)), etc.  My point is that most packages that I contributed to had something else than definitions in them that made reloading problematic.  Thus not all of them will fully reset their state when using `Get` a second time, and sometimes I just need to manually quit the kernel before loading them again.  But I do try to build in some robustness against reloading to make development easier (and accidental double loading by users should definitely not break things).

Comment: It's a nice solution, thank you! There are no side effects in my packages, so I'll go with it. It turned out that problem is caused by subpackages depending on each other with `Needs` instead of `Get`.

Comment: This does not seem to reload the usage definitions.  Is there a workaround?

Comment: @MichaelMcCain Can you show an example?  I don't see why it wouldn't enable changing usage messages.

Comment: @Szabolcs - We can use the exact code in the this thread to illustrate.  I first executed the package notebook.  Then I used`Get["MyPack`"]` in a new notebook to install it.  Then I verified it was installed.  Then I tried changing the line in the package where is says `Foo::usage = "";` to `Foo:usage = "testing"`.  I then re-executed  `Get["MyPack`"]` in the other notebook.  No change.  :/

Comment: sorry for the quotation single and double quotations problems in my question... not sure how to fix that.

Comment: @MichaelMcCain Are you sure you are loading the file you think you are loading?  Did you save the file after modifications?  The code from this answer works as I expect it to work.  You can check which exact file is getting loaded using `FindFile`.  You can see the contents using ``FilePrint["MyPack`"]``  P.S. To be able to write a backtick in code in a comment here, use *double backticks* as the delimiter.

Comment: @Szabolcs - Yes.  I have checked using `FilePrint[]` and that is updating correctly.  However, when I type "Foo" in the same notebook the dropdown still shows the old usage for some reason.  It seems to hold onto the old "Foo".  Not sure how to reset that as well.  Forgive my ineptitude... I'm new to packages.  Thanks for tip on quotations.

Comment: Upon further inspection it appears that typing `?Foo` does in fact update correctly.  However, typing "Foo" and then clicking the dropdown menu for autocompletion does not reveal the updated version.  Autocompletion is not resetting for some reason.

Comment: @Szabolcs This approach seems to create a very serious namespace issue.  To illustrate, suppose we change `helper[x_] := x^2` to `helper[x_] := Module[{y=x^2},y]`.  Then (sadly) `y` becomes a variable in the package context, `EndPackage[]` appends the package context to the `$ContextPath`, and suddenly (after we `Get` the package) we cannot set `y` in the current context.

Comment: @Alan I don't understand what you mean. `y` will be created in the ``MyPack`Private` `` context, not in ``MyPack` ``. Can you give an example?

Comment: @Szabolcs My bad; you are correct. Thanks.

Comment: @Alan If you find a problem, do let me know.

Answer (score 10):

I use these two regularly when developing packages. Not entirely bullet-proof, but enormously helps my workflow. For convenience, you should simply use `Reload` instead of `Needs`. Whatever is changed in the package file will be reloaded.

```
Attributes[Unload] = {Listable};
Unload::nonun = "The System`.` and Global`.` contexts cannot be removed.";
Unload["System`" | "Global`"] := Message[Unload::nonun];
Unload[form_String, fun_: Remove] := 
  Module[{found = Cases[$Packages, _?(StringMatchQ[#, form<>"*"] &)], all},
   all = # <> "*" & /@ found;
   Unprotect /@ all;
   Quiet[fun /@ all];
   Unprotect@$Packages;
   $Packages = DeleteCases[$Packages, Alternatives @@ found];
   Protect@$Packages;
   $ContextPath = DeleteCases[$ContextPath, Alternatives @@ found];
   ];

Attributes[Reload] = {Listable};
Reload[pkg_String] := (
   If[MemberQ[Union[$ContextPath, $Packages], _?(StringMatchQ[#, pkg<>"*"] &)],
     Unload[pkg, ClearAll]]; 
   Get@pkg
   );
```

Note, that `Unload` removes symbols from other packages as well, e.g. `` Unload["Language`"] `` also removes other system-`` Language` `` related functions, not just user-`` Language` `` ones.

Comment: Thank you for answer, but it doesn't work for me. I defined `Reload` and `Unload` in the same notebook, I guess it's ok. And I'm calling `Reload["MyPackage\`"]` instead of `Get["MyPackage\`"]`. It doesn't give any errors, but symptoms are the same. Does `Reload` work correctly for subpackages?

Comment: Sorry, your functions actually work great. My packages depend on each other with `Needs` instead of `Get` and it caused strange problems.

Comment: @lambdas It works now... Had to add proper string matching to handle subcontexts, thanks for pointing it out!