# Why does the syntax highlighter color a local symbol red inside DynamicModule?

Tags: dynamic, manipulate, scoping, syntax-highlighting

I am adding a `Module` inside `DynamicModule` here is an example (thanks to @rm-rf for this simple example)

```
DynamicModule[{x = 1}, Module[{x}, x = 2] ];
```

This Module has a local symbol `x` which happens also to be the name of another local symbol in the enclosing `DynamicModule`.

Yet, the front end is making all occurrences of `x` as red inside the `Module`. Here is a screenshot:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**The question is:** Why would local symbols to one `Module` conflict with local symbols of the enclosing `DynamcModule`?  Yet, the code runs with no problem. So, could this just be that the FE` is confused? Or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Your example is needlessly complicated and makes it harder to convey the point... here's a simple one: `DynamicModule[{x = 1},
  Module[{x}, 
    x = 2] 
  ];`

Comment: or maybe even `DynamicModule[{x}, {x, Module[{x}, x]}]` to see that the variables are different.

Comment: what i meant in the previous comment was evaluate the input `DynamicModule[{x}, {x, Module[{x}, x]}]` and observe the output.

Comment: Related: [Syntax highlighter shows error for Manipulate when it's inside a Block or a Module](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/55121/syntax-highlighter-shows-error-for-manipulate-when-its-inside-a-block-or-a-modu).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think it's just a warning that you have a symbol inside a localization scope that contains a symbol of the same (base) name.  Compare

```
With[{max = 2}, {With[{max = 3}, max], max}]

Module[{max}, max = 2; {Module[{max}, max = 3], max}]

Block[{max}, max = 2; {Module[{max}, max = 3], max}]
```

and so on.  The outputs above are each `{3,2}` and no messages are generated, but the inside `max`s are red.  A bit annoying, perhaps.

If you look at the menu command Help > Why the Coloring... the palette indicates a local scope conflict.  It's not an error, but a possible mistake.  (It's a common mistake for beginners, probably.)

Here is an [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3294/why-are-some-function-names-red/3298#3298) to a related question.

**Update**

Whether to color local scope conflicts and other warning, and what color to use, can be set with the menu command Preferences > Appearance > Errors and Warnings, which is mentioned in the [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3294/why-are-some-function-names-red/3298#3298) mentioned above.

Comment: I agree with Michael E2. It would appear that the _Mathematica_ code editor's syntax analyzer isn't up handling these nested constructs. I suppose it might be considered a bug, but like Michael I take it as a warning.

Comment: @Nasser There are several examples of the highlighter showing something as red when it's not really an error. I'm also not surprised that it can't know well in advance that this _won't_ lead to an error, so better safe than sorry. The only true answer to your question is to treat it as a warning and proceed if you know what you're doing.

Comment: @Nasser You get the same red on the equal sign with `If[x = y,...]`, which is not an error either.  It's often just a mistake.

Comment: @Nasser, they won't clash but can you picture a situation where you used the same name in both nested modules by mistake and then tried to refer to the outermost variable with that common name? Just a warning

Comment: @Nasser, then open Edit, Preferences, Appearance, Error and Warnings, and uncheck the warnings you don't like

Comment: `SetAttributes[f, HoldFirst];f[s_Symbol]:=Module[{s}, ...` isn't necessarily an error. It's just another conflict that get's resolved in a particular way

Comment: @Nasser You seem to be expecting a lot from the syntax highlighter... I can understand your gripe if the kernel leaked the variables between the scopes, but it doesn't. The FE uses what best knowledge it has of mma's syntax, the current scope, the variables defined (previously and now) and does a pretty good job. It is more likely that someone new might do this unknowingly and be confused that the x inside is not what they defined first, so mma gives a warning. Note that it is only a warning, not an actual error, so I don't see what the problem is. As Rojo said, disable it if you don't like it

Answer (score 1):

This is a intended feature.

It is explained by J. Fultz (Wolfram) in http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/2011/Sep/msg00198.html

At that time the last mathematica version was version 8 and the feature didn't exist.

Comment: I understand very well what you mean, but in _this_ case, I think that the explanation would be probably really to complicated.