# FeynCalc "May shadow or be shadowed by other definitions"

Tags: packages, symbols, contexts, feyncalc

So I've downloaded the latest FeynCalc from [this site](http://www.feyncalc.org/download/) and put the extracted folder in `user/me/library/Mathematica/application`, but when I write the command

```
<< HighEnergyPhysics`FeynCalc`
```

*Mathematica* says a bunch of lines saying stuff like:

> `FeynAmp::shdw:` Symbol FeynAmp appears in multiple contexts {`` FeynArts` ``,`` HighEnergyPhysics`FeynCalc`FeynAmp` ``}; definitions in context `` FeynArts` `` may shadow or be shadowed by other definitions. >>

Anyone know what to do, how to install FeynCalc on a Mac properly? I'm using *Mathematica* version 8.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [How to load a package without naming conflicts](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/5563/5) and [Why are some function names red?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3294/5)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like FeynArts did not get patched. Please follow the instructions [here](http://www.feyncalc.org/download/), i.e., reinstall fc820.zip and then do :

```
$LoadPhi=True;
Needs["HighEnergyPhysics`FeynCalc`"];
```

If I find time I update FeynCalc to include a patched FeynArts. The problem is that some examples in fcexamples do not work with FeynArts 3.7 and I need to have a look at how to fix this. Sorry for the trouble, but this is all voluntary work done by Frederik Orelland and myself in our (spare) free time by now.

Comment: I'm sorry, maybe I should've added that after all the red text "errors" the last thing Mathematica wrote was: "FeynArts 3.7 patched for use with FeynCalc" . So maybe it did got patched? I don't know...I'm new to Mathematica and even newer to FeynCalc. BTW Thank you for FeynCalc and all the work you've put into it. Credit will of course be given :)

Comment: Just try to delete the directory HighEnergyPhysics, unzip fc820.zip again and run the answer again.This should work.

Comment: OK I'll give it a try, thanks.

Comment: OK I did exactly like you said and this time no red error messages (instead Mathematica did some crazy things writing out hundreds of lines, in the end it says **Finished! Loading FeynArts, see www.feynarts.de for documentation; FeynArts 3.7 patched for use with FeynCalc**). I think it's good now, but I don't know since I don't know how to test wether it works or not, but I thinks it is OK now. Thank you for your help!

Comment: The next time you start FeynCalc (if you do not want to use FeynArts and Tarcer and Phi you can speed things up by executing first `$LoadPhi=$LoadTARCER = $LoadPhi = False;` followed by `Needs["HighEnergyPhysics`FeynCalc`"];) and then try to run some examples, e.g., from [here](http://www.feyncalc.org/FeynCalcBook/) or you can try some of the .m or .nb files from the fcexamples subdirectory from HighEnergyPhysics (though some will not work unfortunately right now)

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for the tips, I'll post feedback in the future.