# ListDensityPlot with logarithmic scale

Tags: plotting, color, logarithmic-scale, scaling

I can't  figure out how to make ListDensityPlot with both logarithmic coloring and logarithmic scale on both x and y axis.

[Logarithmic scale in a DensityPlot and its legend](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/36830/logarithmic-scale-in-a-densityplot-and-its-legend)

This question worked for ListDensityPlot plot as well - I as able to color plot points in logarithmic coloring scale. But how do you add logarithmic scale to x and y axis as well?

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Why not simply plot the log of the data?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In M11.2 you can use [`ScalingFunctions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ScalingFunctions) to make the ticks logarithmic, for example:

```
DensityPlot[
    Sin[x +y]^2 ,{x, 1, 20}, {y, 1, 20},
    ScalingFunctions -> {"Log", "Log", "Linear"},
    PlotPoints -> 40
]
```

[image]

Change "Linear" to "Log" if you want the values to be logarithmic as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can manually Plot the log of your function and specify [Ticks](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Ticks.html) (e.g. `Ticks -> {{{1, 10}, {2, 100}, {3, 1000}}, {{1, 10}, {2, 100}, {3, 1000}}}`) and [ColorFunction](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ColorFunction.html).