# Logarithmic scaling in a density plot

Tags: plotting, logarithmic-scale

I think the colors will be more distinguishable with the logarithmic scales. How can I do it for the following plot? Thanx.

```
DensityPlot[(μ + η^2), 
    {μ, 0, 0.043}, {η, 0, 0.03}, 
FrameLabel -> {Style[μ, FontSize -> 14, Blue], 
Style[η, FontSize -> 14, Blue]}, 
BaseStyle -> {FontWeight -> Bold, FontSize -> 17}, 
ColorFunction -> "SunsetColors", 
PlotLegends -> 
BarLegend[Automatic, LegendMarkerSize -> 230, LegendMargins -> 5, 
LegendLabel -> Style["Q/(1+C)", FontSize -> 16], 
LabelStyle -> {Bold, FontSize -> 14}]]
```

Comment: Look at [`ScalingFunctions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ScalingFunctions.html). You should be able to use `ScalingFunctions -> {"Linear", "Linear", "Log"}`

Comment: @LukasLang: It is not possible. This command after adding the `->` becomes red!

Comment: What version of Mathematica are you using?

Comment: @LukasLang: Is it the version? I am using 10.4

Comment: Probably - `ScalingFunctions` was updated in 11.0... If you're stuck with 10.4 [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/36830/logarithmic-scale-in-a-densityplot-and-its-legend) should work for you though

Comment: @LukasLang: I just install 11.3 and it works out. Thank U

Comment: @LukasLang: Now I should change the boundaries where has been apeared in these density plots as  region plots. How can I rescale the region plots? I ask this question here https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/175664/is-it-possible-to-have-a-region-plot-with-logarithmic-scales

Comment: @m_goldberg: Dear friend, here the main problem was how to have a logarithmic scale for the third axis (the color!). I don't think this question is off-topic!

Comment: 1) What is `η05`? 2 `ScalingFunctions`, as advised by Lukas, work in v10.4 for this problem - it doesn't matter if they turn red, pink or green - if you evaluate the code, it works.

Comment: @corey979: OMG! Do you actually think that I mean the color?!!! The point was some kind of error that I didn't understand what to do! Yes, in the higher version it is Ok.

Comment: Yes: "It is not possible. This command after adding the `->` becomes red!" Did you even run the code? If so, you would see [this result](https://imgur.com/a/Q5BalDX). `ScalingFunctions` seem to be under-documented, and work properly in instances where the highlighting suggests that it's not valid. The [same thing](https://imgur.com/a/kolDoOI) is with `MaxExtraBandwidths` for `SmoothHistogram`. Run the codes first; panic only if they don't work.

Comment: I have retracted my close vote

Comment: @Lukas this seems like a duplicate of [(36830)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/36830/121) as you referenced.  Do you disagree?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I think so, yes - either that or "Can easily be found in the documentation"

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the comments. I upgrade my software to version 11.3 and the `ScalingFunctions` is available now. This command can scale the third axis (the color), and the figure will be more clear. It should be noted that, as @Lukas Lang said, I used `ScalingFunctions -> {"Linear", "Linear", "Log"}`.