# Is it possible to have a region plot with logarithmic scales?

Tags: plotting, regions, logarithmic-scale

How can I have a region plot with the logarithmic axis? In the following, I have brought the original case which I want to be logarithmic. In this case, I have a density plot and a region plot that shows the realm of validity of the theory. I want to show this figure in logarithmic scales in order to be more clear.

```
η4=0.123663

 con14=-0.1 + 8 E^8 (-((5 μ)/(3 E^(40/3))) + (
 8 π η (BesselI[0, 4] BesselK[0, 4] - 
 BesselI[1, 4] BesselK[1, 4]))/E^8)
 con24=-12.4276 + μ
 con34=-((5 μ)/(3 E^(40/3))) + (
 8 π η (BesselI[0, 4] BesselK[0, 4] - 
 BesselI[1, 4] BesselK[1, 4]))/E^8
 con44=(35 μ)/(36 E^(16/3)) + 
 4 π η ((2 BesselI[0, 4] + 4 BesselI[1, 4]) BesselK[0, 
 4] - (4 BesselI[0, 4] + BesselI[1, 4]) BesselK[1, 4])

 pnrhs4=(1/(η Sqrt[
 161.08 η + 
 35. μ]))(-22.1002 η^(3/2) Sqrt[67.0519 η - 5. μ]
 Sqrt[μ] + 
 2.78971 μ^(
 5/2) + η^2 (-255.832 Sqrt[μ] - 
 0.764016 Sqrt[
 161.08 η + 35. μ]) + η (-240.094 μ^(3/2) + 
 1. Sqrt[161.08 η + 35. μ] + 
 0.00911946 μ Sqrt[161.08 η + 35. μ]))

 CPN4=(1/(η Sqrt[
 161.08 η + 
 35. μ]))(-22.1002 η^(3/2) Sqrt[67.0519 η - 5. μ]
 Sqrt[μ] + 
 2.78971 μ^(
 5/2) + η^2 (-255.832 Sqrt[μ] - 
 0.764016 Sqrt[
 161.08 η + 35. μ]) + η (-240.094 μ^(3/2) + 
 0.00911946 μ Sqrt[161.08 η + 35. μ]))

 QNN4=(60.1862 Sqrt[0.0216024 η + 0.00469384 μ] Sqrt[μ])/η

 Area4 = RegionPlot[{con14 < 0 && con24 < 0 && con34 > 0 && con44 > 0 &&
 Abs[CPN4] < 1 && QNN4 > 0}, {μ, 0, 0.028}, {η, 
 0, η4}, BoundaryStyle -> {Green}, PlotStyle -> {None}, 
 FrameLabel -> Automatic]

 P4 = Show[
 DensityPlot[(QNN4/pnrhs4), {μ, 0, 0.028}, {η, 0, η4}, 
 PlotRange -> {0, 75}, PlotPoints -> 300, 
 PlotRangePadding -> {Automatic, 0.00015}, 
 FrameLabel -> {Style[μ, FontSize -> 14, Blue], 
 Style[η, FontSize -> 14, Blue]}, 
 BaseStyle -> {FontWeight -> Bold, FontSize -> 17}, 
 ColorFunction -> "SunsetColors", 
 PlotLegends -> 
 BarLegend[Automatic, LegendMarkerSize -> 230, LegendMargins -> 5, 
 LegendLabel -> Style["Q/(1+C)", FontSize -> 16], 
 LabelStyle -> {Bold, FontSize -> 14}], 
 FrameTicks -> {{{0, 0.04, 0.08, 0.12}, 
 None}, {{0, 0.006, 0.012, 0.018, 0.024}, None}}], Area4]
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Hi @Jason B. :)

Answer (score 5):

<s>Apparently, `RegionPlot` does not support `ScalingFunctions`.</s> 
It does, but it has to be convinced a little, it applies the scaling functions only to the axes, and also neither the syntax highlighter nor the documentation know about it. Here is a possible workaround (at least for version 11.3).

```
reg = ImplicitRegion[ x + y <= 2 && x^2 + y >= 1 && Abs[x] >= 3/2, {{x, 0, 10}, {y, 0, 10}}];
R = BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[reg];
S = MeshRegion[{Log[#[[1]]], #[[2]]} & /@ MeshCoordinates[R], 
   MeshCells[R, RegionDimension[R]]];
RegionPlot[S, ScalingFunctions -> {"Log", "Linear"}, Axes -> True]
```

[image]

`CountourPlot` accepts `ScalingFunctions` and seems to process them correctly, at least in version 11.3, e.g.

```
ContourPlot[(x - 3)^2 + (y - 4)^2 == 1, {x, 1, 5}, {y, 1, 6},
 ScalingFunctions -> {"Linear", "Log"}
 ]
```

[image]

```
ContourPlot[(x - 3)^2 + (y - 4)^2, {x, 1, 5}, {y, 1, 6},
 ScalingFunctions -> {"Linear", "Log"},
 Contours -> {1}
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: It's worth to mention your version. In v11.3 both codes work; but in v10.4 the first one kills the kernel, and the second produces an empty plot.

Comment: Good point. I'll mention that.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher: I need a region that some constraints are satisfied where. for example `x+y<2 && x^2+y>1 && Abs[x]>2`. Is it possible in contour plot?

Answer (score 4):

You can post-process `RegionPlot` output to rescale the desired coordinate of graphics primitives:

```
rp = RegionPlot[Sin[x] Sin[y] > 1/10, {x, Pi, 4 Pi}, {y, Pi, 4 Pi}, 
   ColorFunction -> "DarkRainbow", ImageSize -> 300]; 
Row[{rp, 
 Show[rp /. GraphicsComplex[c_, prims___] :> GraphicsComplex[{#, Log @ #2}& @@@ c, prims],
   FrameTicks -> {{Charting`ScaledTicks[{Log, Exp}], 
     Charting`ScaledFrameTicks[{Log, Exp}]}, {Automatic, Automatic}} , 
   PlotRange -> All]}, Spacer[10]]
```

[image]

Replace `{#, Log @ #2}& @@@ c` with  `{Log @ #, #2} & @@@ c` to use `Log` scale on the horizontal axis, and with `{Log @ #, Log @ #2} & @@@ c` to have both axes in `Log` scale. With appropriate modifications of the `FrameTicks` settings we get

[image]

Another example:

```
rp = RegionPlot[2 < Abs[ ((x -3 + I  (y/10-5))/10 - 2)/( 2(x-3 + I (y/10-5)) /10- 1)] <5, 
 {x, 3, 20}, {y, 1, 200}, 
 ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", ImageSize -> 300, PlotRange -> All, PlotPoints -> 50]
```

we get

[image]

**Update:** Adding the option `ScalingFunctions -> {"Log", "Log"}` to OP's `DensityPlot` and using post-processing idea on OP's `Area4`:

```
dp2 = DensityPlot[(QNN4/pnrhs4), {μ, 0, 0.028}, {η, 0, η4},
  PlotRange -> {0, 75}, PlotPoints -> 100, 
  PlotRangePadding -> {Automatic, 0.00015}, 
  BaseStyle -> {FontWeight -> Bold, FontSize -> 17}, 
  ColorFunction -> "SunsetColors", 
  FrameTicks -> {{{0, 0.04, 0.08, 0.12},  None}, {{0, 0.006, 0.012, 0.018, 0.024}, None}},
  ScalingFunctions -> {"Log", "Log"}]; 

  Show[dp2, Area4 /.  GraphicsComplex[c_, prims___] :> 
        GraphicsComplex[{Log@#, Log@#2} & @@@ c, {Thick, prims}], ImageSize -> 600]
```

[image]

To confirm that post-processing gives the correct picture, compare the above result to the one obtained using `ContourPlot` with `ScalingFunctions-> {"Log", "Log"}` with `Boole[con14 <= 0 && con24 <=  0 && con34 >= 0 &&  ...]` as the first argument:

```
Area4b = ContourPlot[Boole[con14 <= 0 && con24 <=  0 && con34 >= 0 && con44 >=  0 &&
     Abs[CPN4] <=  1 && QNN4 >=  0], 
  {μ, 0.00001, 0.028}, {η, 0.00001, η4}, ContourStyle -> Green, 
  Contours -> {1}, PlotPoints -> 50, ScalingFunctions -> {"Log", "Log"}, 
  ContourShading -> {None, Opacity[.5, Yellow]}];

 bdg = BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics[Area4b,
   MeshCellStyle -> {2 -> None, 1 -> Directive[Thick, Green]}];

 Show[dp2, bdg, ImageSize -> 400]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank U, but it didn't work out for my problem. I want `{con14 < 0 && con24 < 0 && con34 > 0 && con44 > 0 && Abs[CPN4] < 1 && 
  QNN4 > 0}, {\[Mu], 0, 0.028}, {\[Eta], 0, \[Eta]4}`

Comment: Dear @kglr I want both axes to be logarithmic. On the other hand above command does n't have Thicks. Isn't the shape ugly?! :/

Comment: ... if you want to have Log scale for both axes use ``Show[
   rp /. GraphicsComplex[c_, prims___] :> 
     GraphicsComplex[{Log@#, Log@#2} & @@@ c, prims], 
   FrameTicks -> {{Charting`ScaledTicks[{Log, Exp}], 
      Charting`ScaledFrameTicks[{Log, 
        Exp}]}, {Charting`ScaledTicks[{Log, Exp}], 
      Charting`ScaledFrameTicks[{Log, Exp}]}}, PlotRange -> All, 
   ImageSize -> 300]``

Comment: Dear @kglr: Thanks for your important help. Is it exactly (mathematically) true? I really appreciate you.

Comment: @PerfectFluid, can't say anything re "Is it exactly (mathematically) true":) If you apply the same post-processing to the `ContourPlot` version of the first example above and compare the result to `ContourPlot[... ScalingFunctions->{None,"Log"}]`  you do get the same result.

Comment: Of course :) but, @kglr: It seems that in your answer the vertical axis is exponentiating! On the other hand, the region plot is much bigger than P4 after Show together. I think something is wrong. For example, the values of each axes should be the logarithm of the original values. Shouldn't they? Can you apply your answer to my problem, please?