# How can I make density plot from a data (csv) with Log Scales?

Tags: plotting, import, logarithmic-scale

I have a [data](https://www.dropbox.com/s/dkrniy9fvhav1e5/log%20plot%20data.csv?dl=0) in .csv format and I wish to make a densityplot of the data points but with a log-log scale. I imported the data into Mathematica and used ListDensityPlot with ScalingFunctions -> "Log" but got no changes on axes. Thank you in anticipation of your kind suggestions.

Comment: Do the answers [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/36830/9490) help?

Comment: @JasonB., many thanks for this helpful link. Honestly, this has given me another way my problem could be solved but I will have to develop a model equation first. I am actually trying to perform spectral analysis and correlation on a set of data. Since I am yet to arrive at a model equation, I may still need your suggestions on how DensityPlot could be achieved with the experimental data I have. Thanks

Comment: Is there any way you can put that data where I can access it?  Or write some code that makes fake data very similar to yours?

Comment: @JasonB., here is the link: https://www.dropbox.com/s/dkrniy9fvhav1e5/log%20plot%20data.csv?dl=0